# Find $E(X_1X_2 \mid X_2 X_3)$ for i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli random variables $X_k$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have problems with computing some basic conditional expected value - this is most likely done via transformations of CEV, but I can't get them done properly. Can anyone help me with the following task?

> Let $X_1, \ X_2, \ X_3$ be iid random variables for which $P(X_i = \pm 1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
>   Find $E(X_1X_2 \mid X_2 X_3)$.

Comment: **Hint:** Take a look at the [basic properties of the conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties).

Comment: Did you try to compute the joint distribution of $(X_1X_2,X_2X_3)$? Even brute force yields it readily, since we are talking about a measure on 4 points...

Comment: I really wanted to avoid brute force calculations and use the properties of conditional expectation instead but i have trobles applying them.

Comment: Note that $X_2X_3$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Then use that $X_1$ is independent of $(X_2,X_3)$ hence $E(X_1X_2\mid X_2X_3)=E(X_1)E(X_2\mid X_2X_3)=$ $____$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without brute force:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[X_1X_2|X_2X_3] &= E[E[X_1X_2|X_2X_3,X_2]|X_2X_3] \\
                 &= E[X_2E[X_1|X_2X_3,X_2]|X_2X_3] \\
                 &= E[X_2E[X_1]|X_2X_3]\\
                 &= E[X_2\cdot 0 |X_2X_3]\\
                 &=0
\end{aligned}
$$

First equation is the tower property for conditional expectations, second equation follows because $X_2$ is measurable with regards to the sigma algebra generated by $(X_2, X_2X_3)$ and the third one by independence of $X_1$ and $(X_2, X_2X_3)$.